# React Native Navigation: Check if drawer is opened or not

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-drawer

i have a component that is outside the Drawer tag but it's inside a NavigationContainer.
So i used `useRef` from react to get `navigate` method .

So i use this example: [Navigating without navigation prop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/)

But now, i can't get the state of the drawer (is it opened or closed).

Here's my App component:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import GetInformationByLocation from "./reducers/GetInformationByLocation";
import Wrapper from './components/Wrapper';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import GeoDisplay from "./components/GeoDisplay";
import { Text } from "react-native";
import { navigationRef } from "./helpers/Navigator";

const store = createStore(GetInformationByLocation, applyMiddleware(thunk));
/*
 * TODO:
 * 1. Wrap everything with parent component
 * 2. Search bar
 * 3. Save searched cities.
 * 4. Check if the city is undefined and suggest nearest city.
 * 5. Animated background
 * 6. Fancy and animated font
 * 7. Setup menu преди показване на приложението
 */

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
                <Wrapper />
                <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
                    <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={GeoDisplay} />
                </Drawer.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        </Provider >
    );
}


export default App;
```

and my Wrapper.js Component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { SearchBar, Header } from 'react-native-elements';
import { MainUI } from '../styling/UI';
import * as Navigator from "../helpers/Navigator";
import { DrawerActions } from "@react-navigation/native";

const Wrapper = (props) => {

    const [search, setSearch] = useState(true);

    const openDrawer = () => {
        Navigator.navigationRef.current.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())
        setSearch(false);
    }


    useEffect(() => {
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <StatusBar backgroundColor={"#011E25"} />
            <Header
                leftComponent={{ icon: 'menu', color: '#fff', onPress: () => { openDrawer() } }}
                centerComponent={{ text: 'COVID Bulgaria', style: { color: '#fff' } }}
                rightComponent={{ icon: 'home', color: '#fff' }}
                backgroundColor={'#011E25'}
            />
            {search &&
                <View>
                    <SearchBar placeholder="Търси град" containerStyle={MainUI.searchContainer} />
                </View>
            }
        </>
    )

}

export default Wrapper;
```

I dispatch `openDrawer()` action with navigationRef
`Navigator.navigationRef.current.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())`
but can't get status of the drawer.

I've tried many ways but not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `useIsDrawerOpen` can helps

Comment: @NishargShah Don't work at all, because the <Wrapper /> component is not in the <Drawer.Navigator>

Comment: I get this error when i try `Error: Couldn't find a drawer. Is your component inside a drawer navigator?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if drawer is open by getting the navigation state:

```js
const state = navigationRef.current.getRootState();
const isDrawerOpen = state.history.some((it) => it.type === 'drawer');
```

The above code assumes that drawer is at root. If it's nested, you'll need to traverse the state to find the state object with `type: 'drawer'`.

It's not clear why you need to check it from the question. Normally you shouldn't need to check it. If you dispatch `DrawerActions.openDrawer()` if drawer is already open, nothing will happen. So the check is unnecessary. If you want to close the drawer if it was open, you can dispatch `DrawerActions.toggleDrawer()` instead.

Comment: I'm gonna try with this method. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper class like:

```
class DrawerHandler() {
 
 openDrawer() {
     this.drawerOpened = true;  
 }

closeDrawer() {
     this.drawerOpened = false;    
 }

getDrawerStatus() {
  return this.drawerOpened;
 }
}

export default new DrawerHandler();
```

Use open and close functions on drawer opening and closing and get function to get status of the drawer

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to determine if drawer is open or closed, you can do the following:

import { useDrawerStatus } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

// ...

const isDrawerOpen = useDrawerStatus() === 'open';